# java object instantiation to return null?

Tags: java, object, null

Maybe it looks like a very ordinary question but I am also surprised at how this can be possible.
I am creating an object in one of my class using the following statement:

```
TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
```

it returns null. However when passing the `testVO` object to a method( which parses an Excel sheet and sets the data in VO) it does not throw `NullPointerException`( In eclipse debug mode, testVO value is shown as null). When trying to use the same object in next set of statements, it throws the NPE.

I am also surprised why above statement returns null and not assigning the memory to the object.

Please note when creating the `TestVO` class object in another class, it is working fine. This is happening only a particular class.

Below is the class source code:

```
public class SheetParser {
public SheetParser() {

}
public void parseSheet(Workbook workbook, List<TestVO> list) {
    TestVO testVO = null;
    Row row = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    String header = null;
    boolean hasHeaderRow = false;
    boolean hasDataRow = false;
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = rows.next();
            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                hasHeaderRow = true;
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        cell = row.getCell(i++);
                        if (cell == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        header = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        if (header == null || "".equals(header.trim())) {
                            break;
                        }
                        headers.add(header.toUpperCase());
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                validateHeaders(headers);
            } else {
                hasDataRow = true;
                testVO = new TestVO();
                // HERE the above statement failed to initialized the object
                // and shows the testVO as null
                // But below in setRowData method, value is set in testVo
                // object after reading from excel sheet
                boolean error = setRowData(testVO, headers, row, errorList);
                if (!error) {
                    list.add(testVO);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorList.add(e.getMessage());
    }
    if (!hasHeaderRow) {
        errorList.add("Uploaded Excel file is invalid, headers missing");
    }
    if (!hasDataRow) {
        errorList
                .add("Uploaded Excel file is invalid, data row(s) are missing.");
    }
}

private boolean setRowData(TestVO testVO, List<String> headersList,
        Row row, List<String> errors) {
    boolean error = false;
    boolean allCellsBlank = true;
    List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String rowPrefixText = "At Row #";
    for (int i = 0; i < headersList.size(); i++) {
        String header = headersList.get(i);
        String value = "";
        try {
            row.getCell(i).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            value = row.getCell(i).toString().trim();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        try {
            if (header.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")) {
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
                    errorList.add(rowPrefixText + row.getRowNum()
                            + ", ABC is required.");
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    testVO.setAbc(value);
                    allCellsBlank = false;
                }
            } else if (header.equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ")) {
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
                    errorList.add(rowPrefixText + row.getRowNum()
                            + ", XYZ is required.");
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    testVO.setXyz(value);
                    allCellsBlank = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorList.add(rowPrefixText + row.getRowNum()
                    + ", incorrect data / format in column:" + header);
            error = true;
        }
    }
    if (allCellsBlank) {
        error = true;
    } else if (!errorList.isEmpty()) {
        errors.addAll(errorList);
    }
    return error;
}

private void validateHeaders(List<String> headersList) throws Exception {
    if (!headersList.contains("ABC")) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Headers - missing ABC");
    } else if (!headersList.contains("XYZ")) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Headers - missing XYZ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the **exact** code

Comment: Please check source code added, also mention the exact location where is the issue

Comment: Could you also add the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testVO` cannot be `null` after this line:

```
TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
```

If you see that it is `null`, maybe it is because you hover over the variable before it is initialized, and eclipse doesn't update the shown value.

You can add:

```
if (testVO == null) {
    System.out.println("testVO  is null although everyone says it cannot be.");
}
```

directly after `TestVO testVO = new TestVO();` and see if the message is shown.

Comment: You are right whoAmI. The eclipse does not update the value and shows it as null. Unfortunately for me, at the same line in my code, testVo and its one of attribute getter method is used for comparasion which in actual throws the NPE. The eclipse was showing wrong value shown for testVO.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

This cannot assign null to testVO.

```
TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
```

Probably **1)** you use testVO before this line is executed,
or **2)** after this line is executed, you set it to null yourself
and then you use it when it's null already. So check your code carefully.

Comment: I have checked my code and 100% sure about, nothing is wrong logically. The source code is added for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `TestVO` class ,there is overridden `toString()` method returns `null`,that's why on debugging mode you are getting null.But in reality there is object of your class because you doesn't get `NullPointerException`.

I hope this is partial solution of your problem